# ¿Cómo subir imágenes en laravel 4.2?

Tags: laravel

Estoy tratando de guardar logotipo en mi base de datos con la ruta de la imagen en laravel 4.2, el problema es que desconosco el codigo que se utilice para esto.

Tengo un formulario y al guardar, se guarda todo correctamente pero la imagen se va a una ruta Fake. he buscado informacion pero solo encuentro como guardar imagenes en la version 5 y hay cosas diferentes a la 4.

Les agradeceria mucho si alguien pudiera ayudarme, aqui mi codigo:

**Formulario (Vista)..**

```
<form id="myform" class="form-horizontal form-label-left input_mask" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="/SavePost">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-2"></div>
            <div class="col-md-8 col-sm-8 col-xs-12">
                <!-- creado_por -->
               <div id="" class="form-group ">
                <input type="hidden" class="form-control" id="creadoPor" name="creado_por" value="{{ Auth::user()->id }}">
              </div>

                <div id="" class="form-group validar">
                    <label class="control-label" for="razon_social">Razón social de la empresa
                    </label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="razonSocial" name="razon_social" placeholder="Razón social de la empresa" data-tipo="nombre" autocomplete="off" onkeyup="removerError($(this))">
                </div>
                <div id="" class="form-group validar">
                    <label class="label-control" for="alias">Alias de la empresa</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="alias" name="alias" placeholder="Alias de la empresa" data-tipo="nombre"autocomplete="off" onkeyup="removerError($(this))">
                </div>


                                 <!-- permitir_logo -->
            <div  id="" class="form-group validar">
               <label >Permitir Logo</label><br>
                <select  class="form-control esconder" id="permitir" name="permitir_logo"
               onkeyup="removerError($(this))" required>
                      <option disabled="" selected="" value="0">Selecciona una opción</option>
                      <option value="1">Si</option>
                      <option value="0">No</option>

                </select>
            </div>

                <!-- logotipo -->
                  <div class="form-group has-feedback">
                    <input type="hidden" class="form-control validar mostrar"  placeholder="logo tipo" name="logotipo" id="img">
                  </div>

             </div>
          </div>
         </form>
```

**Ajax(JS)...**

```
$('#guardar').on('click',function(){

 if (error==false) {
    datos.creadoPor=$('#creadoPor').val();
    datos.razonSocial=$('#razonSocial').val();
    datos.alias=$('#alias').val();
    datos.permitir=$('#permitir').val();
    datos.img=$('#img').val();
            $.ajax({
        url: 'nueva_empresa',
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {
            emp: JSON.stringify(datos)


        }
    }).done(function(response) {
        $("#myform")[0].reset();
        $('#myModal').modal('toggle');
        notif({
            msg: "<b>Cliente Registrado",
            type: "success",
            position: "center",
            timeout: 3000
        });

         cargarTabla();


    }).fail(function() {


    }).always(function() {

    });
 }
});
```

**Funcion del controlador...**

```
 public function nueva_empresa()
{
    $empresas = json_decode(Input::get('emp'));
    $emp     = new Empresas;
    $emp ->creado_por   = $empresas->creadoPor;
    $emp ->razon_social = $empresas->razonSocial;
    $emp ->alias        = $empresas->alias;
    $emp ->permitir_logo= $empresas->permitir;
    $emp ->logotipo     = $empresas->img;


    $emp->save();
    return $emp;

}
```

Comment: Bienvenid@ a [es.so], te sugiero que hagas el [tour] y de paso ganes tu primera medalla, también es muy importante que leas [ask] para poder mejorar tus preguntas y que sean bien recibidas por la comunidad. Adicional, ya intentaste buscando por: _laravel 4 image upload_

Comment: Muchas Gracias!!!